# MongoDB _id beyond 9999999

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with more then 10M documents.
I am trying to get the biggest _id form that Mongo collection with PHP

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array())->sort(array('_id'=>-1))->limit(1);
foreach ($cursor as $doc)
{
    echo $doc['_id'];
}
```

I am getting 9999999 as the answer every time.

This also doesn't work

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('_id'=>array('$gte'=>'5000000')))->sort(array('_id'=>-1))->limit(1);
```

I also tried with the Aggregate

```
$query = array(
    array('$match'=>array('_id'=>array('$gte'=>'5000000'))),
    array('$group'=>array('_id'=>'','max_id'=>array('$max'=>'$_id'))),

);
$res = $collection->aggregate($query);
print_r($res);
```

Same 9999999 pops up but this time it takes 6-7 seconds to compute.

It seems to me that there is a limit in MongoDB which prevents me from doing beyond 9999999

Comment: Have you tried using `'$gte'=>5000000` instead of a string?

Comment: Yes got the same result.

Comment: I think that the issue is that it is a string, I am importing it again right now and the _id will be NumberInt()

Comment: Note that numberint is 32bit, if you intend this collection to get very large then int 32 has a limit of like 2b, you might wanna future proof that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't directly show it, but it appears that your `_id` values are numeric strings, not numbers.  Strings sort alphabetically, so `'9999999'` (and even `'9'`) would come before `'10000000'` in your descending sort.

Your best option is probably to update your docs to use a numeric data type for `_id` and then they will sort as you're expecting.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, I re-imported form MySQL with php's (int) and it is working now.